# How to set an env variable with double quotes in dokku of a create-react-app based app?

Tags: environment-variables, dokku, create-react-app

I'm having trouble getting a create-react-app based application to correctly load environment variables containing double quotes:

First the dokku config shows this:

```
dokku config admin
=====> admin config vars
REACT_APP_API:           "https://example.com"
dokku@DokkuVM:~$
```

and my fetch calls look like this:

```
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/v1/whatever`)
```

which webpack compiles to (and of course does not work):

`fetch(("\"https://example.com\"") + '/api/v1/whatever')`

A similar setup is working locally, in my .env file I have:

```
REACT_APP_API="http://example.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use double quotes when setting values like that. Instead, do this:

```
dokku config:set APP_NAME REACT_APP_API=http://example.com
```